# How to convert integer to date format in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to convert integer data from my data frame in R, to date format.

The data is under column named svcg_cycle within orig_svcg_filtered data frame.

The original data looking something like 200502, 200503, and so forth, and I expect to turn it into yyyy-mm-dd format.

I am trying to use this code:

```
as.Date(orig_svcg_filtered$svcg_cycle, origin = "2000-01-01")
```

but the output is not something that I expected:

```
[1] "2548-12-15" "2548-12-15" "2548-12-15" "2548-12-15" "2548-12-15"
```

while it is supposed to be 2005-02-01, 2005-03-01, and so forth.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have

```
x <- c(200502, 200503)
```

Then

```
as.Date(x, origin = "2000-01-01")
```

tells R you want the days 200,502 and 200,503 days after 2000-01-01. From `help("as.Date")`:

> as.Date will accept numeric data (the number of days since an epoch),
>   but only if origin is supplied.

So, integer data gives days after the origin supplied, not some sort of numeric code for the dates like 200502 for "2005-02-01".

What you want is

```
as.Date(paste(substr(x, 1, 4), substr(x, 5, 6), "01", sep = "-"))

# [1] "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
```

The

```
paste(substr(x, 1, 4), substr(x, 5, 6), "01", sep = "-")
```

part takes your integers and creates strings like

```
# [1] "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
```

Then `as.Date()` knows how to deal with them.

You could alternatively do something like

```
as.Date(paste0(x, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")

# [1] "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
```

This just pastes on an `"01"` to each element (for the day), converts to character, and tells `as.Date()` what format to read the date into. (See `help("as.Date")` and `help("strptime")`).

Answer (score 0):

I like to use Regex to fix these kinds of string formatting issues. `as.Date` by default only checks for several standard date formats like YYYY-MM-DD. `origin` is used when you have an integer date (i.e. seconds from some reference point), but in this case your date is actually not an integer date, rather it's just a date formatted as a string of integers.

We simply split the month and day with a dash, and add a day, in this case the first of the month, to make it a valid date (you must have a day to store it as a date object in R). The Regex bit captures the first 4 digits in group one and final two digits in group two. We then combine the two groups, separated by dashes, along with the day.

```
as.Date(gsub("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})", "\\1-\\2-01", x))

[1] "2005-02-01" "2005-03-01"
```

You don't need to specify `format` in this case, because YYYY-MM-DD is one of the standard formats `as.Date` checks, however, the format argument is `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`